# For a given differential equation can there exist many integrating factors?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In this [article](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html)  , solutions to inexact differential equations are discussed. The author comes to this equation in a critical step:

$$ M_y u + u_y M= N_x u +u_x N$$

The subscripts denote partials

So, my understanding of this is that if we have some function $ u(x,y)$ for which the above equation is solved given an $ M$ and $N$ , then we can solve our inexact differential equation. However how many such unique  $u$ functions exist? (Disregarding scaling )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem can be rewritten as
$$
N u_x - M u_y = (M_y - N_x) u
$$
which is a first-order linear PDE. Corresponding boundary-value problems may be analyzed by using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Existence and uniqueness results follow from Picard-Lindelöf, and associated mathematical results.